# What is index do I need create?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have query which sometimes really slow, how can I speed it up?

```
SELECT PRODUCTS.ID,
    SPECIALPRODUCTGROUPS."id" AS "isProductGroup",
    PRODUCTS."OEM",
    PRODUCTS.NAME,
    MAIN."stockBalance" AS STOCKBALANCE,
    PRODUCTS."minShippingRate",
    PRODUCTS."externalId",
    ARTICLE,
    "categoryId",
    BRAND,
    PRICES."price" AS "price"
FROM PUBLIC."Products" AS PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN PUBLIC."Prices" AS PRICES ON PRODUCTS.ID = PRICES."productId"
AND PRICES."accountId" = 13576
AND PRICES."price" >= 0
AND PRICES."price" <= 337802
INNER JOIN PUBLIC."RegionalWarehouseStockBalances" AS MAIN ON PRODUCTS.ID = MAIN."productId"
AND MAIN."warehouseId" = 1
AND MAIN."stockBalance" > 0
LEFT JOIN PUBLIC."SpecialProductGroups" AS SPECIALPRODUCTGROUPS ON PRODUCTS."productGroupId" = SPECIALPRODUCTGROUPS."productGroupId"
AND SPECIALPRODUCTGROUPS."accountId" = 13576
AND NOW() < SPECIALPRODUCTGROUPS."finishedAt"
WHERE PRODUCTS."active" = TRUE
ORDER BY BRAND ASC
LIMIT 50
```

There is explain of this query
[Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ1hK.png)

I can't add explain in text because stackoverflow complains about the amount of code

Added explain https://explain.depesz.com/s/4UAg

I tried to create indexes on RegionalWarehouseStockBalances, but all my variants doesn't help me
I am using PostgreSQL 12

Comment: How about pasting the explain text [here](https://explain.depesz.com/) and sharing a link to it? The picture cuts some parts off.

Comment: @Zegarek Ty for advice. Added explain analyze

Comment: It seems like one of those index-only scans that aren't index-only - it's doing heap fetches most of the time. You could try and include a non-key column in the index using [`INCLUDE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6). `create index p_price_prod_idx on table public."Prices" ("productId","accountId") include ("price");` The current index name also seems like you've been tinkering with partial indexes - what's your `where` condition at the moment? Did you try to run `vacuum analyze public."Prices";` to clean up the table and index before the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
VACUUM prices;
```

so that the index-only scan has few "heap fetches". That will make all the difference.

Reduce `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor` for that table so that the system vacuums the table frequently.

Comment: Thanks you, I will try and let you know about result